# VBA Dlookup work with embedded table, but not with linked tables

Tags: mongodb-lookup

I'm working with a very simple table:

VendorID     Primary Key
VendorType   Short Text
VendorName   Short Text
VendorNumber Short Text

I have a very simple line of vba code:
dlookup("VendorName","aSuppliers","VendorID = " & 8)

It works perfectly. UNTIL I split the database and then I get a NULL value.

What's really odd is that:
dlookup("VendorType","aSuppliers","VendorID = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting
dlookup("VendorNumer","aSuppliers","VendorID = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting.

I even created a new field (VendorName2), copied and pasted the data from VendorName.
dlookup("VendorName2","aSuppliers","VendorID = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting.

I've also tried using square brackets:

dlookup("[VendorName]","[aSuppliers]","[VendorID] = " & 8) returns NULL
dlookup("[VendorType]","[aSuppliers]","[VendorID] = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting
dlookup("[VendorNumer]","[aSuppliers]","[VendorID] = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting
dlookup("[VendorName2]","[aSuppliers]","[VendorID] = " & 8) returns the result I'm expecting